# Oracle: missing SELECT keyword, when using WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an "Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword" error message when I run the following query.

The purpose of the query is to obtain the name of the actor that starred (starred, as indicated by ord=1) in the most movies for each decade.

I tested T1 and T2 independently and they work. I do not see what I am doing wrong.

Could you please give me an explanation?

Note: this is homework

```
        WITH T1 AS
                (SELECT decade, MAX(countTitle) maxCount
                FROM (
                    SELECT FLOOR(yr/10)*10 decade, name, COUNT(title) countTitle
                    FROM movie JOIN casting ON (movie.id = casting.movieid)
                        JOIN actor ON (actor.id = casting.actorid)
                    WHERE  (casting.ord = 1)
                    GROUP BY FLOOR(yr/10)*10, name
                )
                GROUP BY decade)
            T2 AS
                (SELECT decade, MAX(countTitle) maxCount
                FROM T1)
            T3 AS
                (SELECT FLOOR(yr/10)*10 decade, name, COUNT(title) countTitle
                FROM movie JOIN casting ON (movie.id = casting.movieid)
                    JOIN actor ON (actor.id = casting.actorid)
                WHERE  (casting.ord = 1)
                GROUP BY FLOOR(yr/10)*10, name
                )
        SELECT T3.decade, T3.name, T3.countTitle
        FROM T2 INNER JOIN T3
        ON T3.decade = T2.decade AND T3.countTitle = T2.maxCount;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need commas between the T<sub>i</sub>s?

Comment: That was probably it. I added the commas and I now get a different error message (a good sign). Thanks!

Comment: The query is now working. The code I posted was incorrect and I had to make a change to T1.

Comment: Hi Judge Mental, my apologies, it is done now. I had acknowledged the answer as useful, but did not notice the "Accept" button. I might have to go back to all my previous questions to mark them as answered...